# Could someone explain this command for me:

Tags: linux, shell, sed

Could someone explain this command:

```
sudo sed -i 's/app, Module,/app,/' /home/ubuntu/workspace/flask_blog/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_uploads.py
```

what does the "sed" command do ?

Comment: What does `man sed` tell you?

Comment: It replaces the string `app, Module,` with `app,` in that file.

Answer (score 1):

It removes the first occurence of `Module,` if it appears after `app,` in the file `/home/ubuntu/workspace/flask_blog/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_uploads.py`